# Filebeat only harvests some of the csv files

Tags: logstash, pipeline, filebeat, elk

I have configured filebeat to send different **(VoIP/SMS)** csv files to logstash. However, only VoIP .csv files get shipped to logstash.
Csv files are under different folders.

```
logs/sms
logs/voip
```

I had another issue, [described in this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196346/logstash-does-not-process-files-sent-by-filebeat). I managed to partially sort that out by creating tags in filebeat for these .csvs.

```
pwd
/usr/share/filebeat/logs
ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 106496 Dec  4 03:39 sms
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 131072 Dec  8 01:49 voip

 ls -ltr voip | head -4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7933 Dec  4 03:39 sms_cdr_1010.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7974 Dec  4 03:39 sms_cdr_101.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7949 Dec  4 03:39 sms_cdr_1009.csv

 ls -ltr voip | head -4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11616 Dec  4 03:39 voip_cdr_10.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11533 Dec  4 03:39 voip_cdr_1.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11368 Dec  4 03:39 voip_cdr_0.csv
```

Filebeat only starts harvesting voip .csvs

```
2019-12-08T02:37:18.872Z    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:72   Loading Inputs: 1
2019-12-08T02:37:18.872Z    INFO    log/input.go:138    Configured paths: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs/voip/*]
2019-12-08T02:37:18.872Z    INFO    input/input.go:114  Starting input of type: log; ID: 801046369164835837 
2019-12-08T02:37:18.872Z    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:106  Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
2019-12-08T02:37:18.977Z    INFO    log/harvester.go:255    Harvester started for file: /usr/share/filebeat/logs/voip/voip_cdr_185.csv
2019-12-08T02:37:18.978Z    INFO    log/harvester.go:255    Harvester started for file: /usr/share/filebeat/logs/voip/voip_cdr_2809.csv
2019-12-08T02:37:18.979Z    INFO    log/harvester.go:255    Harvester started for file: /usr/share/filebeat/logs/voip/voip_cdr_2847.csv
```

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
     - logs/sms/*
  tags: ["sms"]
  paths:     
     - logs/voip/*
  tags: ["voip"]

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]

logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
   }
}

filter {
 if "sms" in [tags] {
     csv {
    columns => ['Date', 'Time', 'PLAN', 'CALL_TYPE', 'MSIDN', 'IMSI', 'IMEI']
    separator => ","
    skip_empty_columns => true
    quote_char => "'"
    }
  }
 if "voip" in [tags] { 
  csv {
    columns => ['Record_Nb', 'Date', 'Time', 'PostDialDelay', 'Disconnect-Cause', 'Sip-Status','Session-Disposition', 'Calling-RTP-Packets-Lost','Called-RTP-Packets-Lost', 'Calling-RTP-Avg-Jitter','Called-RTP-Avg-Jitter', 'Calling-R-Factor', 'Called-R-Factor', 'Calling-MOS', 'Called-MOS', 'Ingress-SBC', 'Egress-SBC', 'Originating-Trunk-Group', 'Terminating-Trunk-Group']
    separator => ","
    skip_empty_columns => true
    quote_char => "'"
     }
  } 
}

output {
     if "sms" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "smscdr_index"
            }
        stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
        }
     }
  if "voip" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "voipcdr_index"
            }
        stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed it solution [here] (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-send-two-different-log-file-types-from-the-same-source-directory-to-logstash/180366/6)                                  ```filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
     - logs/sms/*.csv
  tags: ["sms"]

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:  
     - logs/voip/*.csv
  tags: ["voip"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below configuration,

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
     - /usr/share/filebeat/logs/sms/*.csv
  tags: ["sms"]
  paths:     
     - /usr/share/filebeat/logs/voip/*.csv
  tags: ["voip"]

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]

logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
```

Comment: hi, thanks it works, I've figured out the solution and it's in the comment above, however I could not figure out how to format my answer  in a **block code format** :) ... thanks though